# Distinguish model type while deserializing json data in Ext JS store

Tags: javascript, extjs, deserialization, extjs4.2, extjs5

In Ext JS I have data store with JSON reader. 
I generate models from classes on server side, with same hierarchy - eg. on server I have `CustomerDto` class which extends `BaseDto` class; 
on client side I also have `CustomerDto` which extends `BaseDto`, and `BaseDto` extends `Ext.data.Model`.

Let's say I define data store with model `SuperCustomerDto` (which extends `CustomerDto`) and send mixed list of `SuperCustomerDto` and `CustomerDto` from server, they are always deserialized as `CustomerDto`.

Is there a way to configure data store in Ext JS, so it can distinguish actual model type? So in my case list should contain few `SuperCustomerDto` and few `CustomerDto`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ext JS 5 you can set `typeProperty` which will indicate the type of the model to be created.

Example store:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'CustomerDto',
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            typeProperty: 'cls',
            rootProperty: 'data'
        }
    }
});
```

Example data:

```
[
    { cls: 'CustomerDto',      id: 1, a: 'a' },
    { cls: 'SuperCustomerDto', id: 2, a: 'a', b: 'b' }
]
```

If `typeProperty` is set to `cls`, reader will conver first array element to `CustomerDto`, and second to `SuperCustomerDto`.

In Ext JS prior to 5 AFAIK there is no build-in support for that. To mimic this behaviour you should override `Ext.data.reader.Reader.extractData` method.

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/b2LS5/1/